# Remove the space between single characters only

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following string and I'm trying to remove the space between **only the single characters**, thus leaving WORDS properly spaced.

Example string

```
This is my s e n t e n c e.
```

The result needs to be:

```
This is my sentence.
```

Another example of:

```
Words must remain properly spaced but **s i n g l e** characters **l i k e** this are joined.
```

Would become:

```
Words must remain properly spaced but **single** characters **like** this are joined.
```

Comment: Obviously, asking us ...

Comment: @VoidStar Perhaps that would be a better edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=\b\w)\s(?=\w\b)", "");
```

Comment: The expression works for both test cases: string res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=\b\w)\s(?=\w\b)", "");

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but try this.

```
string value = "w o r d";
char[] sentence = value.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < value.length+1; i++) {
    if (sentence[++i] = " " && sentence [i] != " ") {
        sentence [i] = sentence [++i];
    }
}
```

Comment: this won't compile, will throw out of range exceptions, and will probably fail otherwise...